# Isaiah 53 How does Israel's suffering atone for the sins of the nations?

Tags: gentiles, rashi, am-yisrael-jewish-nation, isaiah-yeshaya-the-book, kaparah-atonement

Isaiah 53:4
Indeed, he bore our illnesses, and our pains-he carried them, yet we accounted him as plagued, smitten by God and oppressed.
דאָכֵן חֳלָיֵנוּ הוּא נָשָׂא וּמַכְאֹבֵינוּ סְבָלָם וַאֲנַחְנוּ חֲשַׁבְנֻהוּ נָגוּעַ מֻכֵּה אֱלֹהִים וּמְעֻנֶּה:

[Rashi comments](http://www.chabad.org/library/bible_cdo/aid/15984#showrashi=true):

> Indeed, he bore our illnesses: Heb. אָכֵן, an expression of ‘but’ in
>   all places. But now we see that this came to him not because of his
>   low state, but that he was chastised with pains **so that all the
>   nations be atoned for with Israel’s suffering**. The illness that should
>   rightfully have come upon us, he bore.

Is there indication in Scripture, prior to this passage in Isaiah 53, that suggests the suffering of one can atone for the sin of another?  What leads Rashi to this understanding/interpretation?  How can the suffering of one atone for the sins of another?

Comment: This concept is also said regarding Rebbi's suffering (BM 95a).

Comment: Who is Rebbi?  I searched the reference you cite, but I don't even know what it is.

Comment: Rebbi Yehudah Hanasi, redactor of the Mishna. BM is shorthand for Bava Metzi'a, a tractate of Gemara. On page *85a (typo in original post) there, it says that the ground was so moist that holes dug began puddling, to the point that no rain was necessary during Rebbi's lifetime. This was because of the suffering that Rebbi endured, described in the previous part of the Gemara. It makes a similar comment there regarding Rabbi Elazar, a contemporary of Rebbi, whose suffering allowed for nobody to die prematurely.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I don't have a thorough answer about the mechanism of substitutive atonement -- in general, in Judaism, a person dies for his own sin. In those instances where it LOOKS like one is dying for another, the rabbis explain that the death of a particular person is designed to inspire others to repent and avoid their own punishment. The death brings about atonement by driving a change in the other person or people.

However there are a few other important concepts which I am willing to piece together:

1. [I don't have the medrashic source for this]

> "Chazal tell us that if the nations knew how much the Bais HaMikdash
>   benefited them they would not have destroyed it. They would have
>   placed armed guards around it to protect it. "

http://revach.net/parshas-hashavua/quick-vort/Parshas-Balak-Bilam-Says-A-Heartfelt-Ma-Tovu/481

So Israel's prayers and sacrifices (and one might assume, the continued prayers after the sacrificial system ended) had an effect on behalf of the world which would, I guess, include atonement through prayer.

2. From www.drazin.com

> Yet, amid all this persecution, the Jews have relentlessly "interceded for the [Gentile] transgressors," in compliance with:
>
> Jeremiah 29:7
>
> And seek the welfare of the city to which I have exiled you, and pray to the L-rd on its behalf, for in its welfare you will have peace.

So despite suffering at the hands of the nations, by following the injunction to pray for the well being of the various governments, Israel has achieved results on behalf of others.

3. The Drazin site also includes the following (though without a source for the idea):

> The Jews have certainly borne the iniquities of the Gentiles: throughout history, they have been discriminated against, oppressed, tortured, raped, robbed, and murdered. By submitting themselves to this treatment and acknowledging it to be His will, they have justified and sanctified G-d's Name.

This goes back, somewhat, to the statement I made above -- one person/group's suffering should inspire others by showing the suffering/death as a statement of piety which drives others to try and be more pious.

Comment: Was that the concept of atonement by sacrifice of animals--that the innocent suffer because of unrighteous choices and unrighteous deeds?  From the very first sin, God provides a covering for man's nakedness with the skin of an animal.  Doubtless their clothes reminded them daily of how the innocent animal suffered for/as a result of their disobedient choice.

Comment: Sacrifice (which is occasionally animal, but not necessarily so) was about losing something of value and reminding oneself of subservience to God. But atonement existed without animals because other things can be lost, and there are other ways of expressing an understanding that one has rebelled by violating a law.

Comment: I wonder if this may have been what was intended originally by early Jewish followers of the Nazarene, before they were persecuted, and the following hijacked, paganized, hellenized, and romanized.  Jewish scholars suggest he was crucified by compromised religious leaders under the influence of Rome.  If so, then, when properly understood, he did fulfill this prophecy, and God used it to call countless souls who believe his suffering was because of their sin, to turn from sin and toward the God of Abraham, Isaac, and Jacob.  He suffered with countless innocent Jews generation upon generation.

Comment: That's problematic, not the least because humans aren't fit to be sacrificed, crucifixion isn't a proper method of execution, let alone sacrifice, and there was no prophecy about a human sacrifice. Also, if you check the Drazin site, you will see many other problems.

Comment: "The Jews have certainly borne the iniquities of the Gentiles: throughout history, they have been discriminated against, oppressed, tortured, raped, robbed, and murdered. By submitting themselves to this treatment and acknowledging it to be His will, they have justified and sanctified G-d's Name."  Surely this does not exempt from the picture any Jews who were crucified or executed?  The passage is not about sacrifice; it is about the innocent servant of God (Jew) who suffers the consequences of one who sins.  Why would we not see this to be true also of the Nazarene who was a Jew?

Comment: +1 Drazin:  http://www.drazin.com/    Another anti-missionary site:  https://jewsforjudaism.org/  with an outstanding work that helps put things in perspective:  https://jewsforjudaism.org/wp-content/uploads/2013/09/FaithStrengthened.pdf  More specific in regard to this topic:  Chapter 22, p.53

Comment: In delivering from false doctrine, we would not leave an innocent Jew out of the picture of those who sanctified God's name through his suffering,  nor compare this one's suffering that only lasted hours with the suffering of those in the holocaust whose sufferings lasted longer.  The suffering of one Jew caused knowledge of God, His law and His people to be distributed around the world.  The suffering of Jews in the holocaust caused the world to look on you.   And the christian who followed the Nazarene would see in each of your eyes, the Jew they had pierced.

Comment: "Why would we not see this to be true also of the Nazarene who was a Jew? " Because the text is not speaking of a single individual, but on the suffering of a nation. It is the collective suffering, not one instance. The holocaust was an action against a group.

Comment: Isaiah moves from speaking of Israel as servant in a plural sense, to personifying all of Israel as one man.  I begin to see.  The impact it has on my psyche when I read it, knowing the servant is Israel, is that I recognize the suffering of even one Jew as the suffering shared by all in every generation, for generation upon generation; and when I hear "for our transgressions" I know I share in the responsibility for your suffering, because I transgressed the laws of God--it causes me to withdraw from anything that causes your suffering, and cling to the God you serve and the laws you preserve

Comment: Danno, How do you understand the shift from speaking of the servant as a nation to the servant as a he--or, as you explained it, from speaking of the nation of Israel as "My servant"  collectively with plural pronouns, to speaking of Israel as 'My servant" with singular pronouns?--do the sages address this more personal perspective?  This seems to be what causes some to expect the passage would be fulfilled by a particular Jew.

Comment: often, the singualr is used to make a point about the unity of the people as a singular unit, other times to show the relationship between God and the people as the metaphorical relationship between individuals (look at Ex 4:22 and the rashi on Ex 19:2)

Comment: It is then saying the whole of your people would suffer as one--as in the Holocaust.  So do the Jews understand this to have been fulfilled in the holocaust?

Comment: AFAICT many Jews don't try to look for precise fulfillments of prophecy these days. We aren't on that level to understand exactly when a prophecy is fulfilled.

Comment: Well, why are the prophecies given then?

Comment: Prophecy is more often a message to people living at a particular time about why it is important to do tshuva at that time. Prophecy is simply a message from God and most of those messages aren't predictions per se, rather warnings. Some are predictions but we aren't supposed to live in fear of, or trying to interpret or predict that potential.

Comment: Was it not through reading the prophecy of Jeremiah that Daniel realized the time decreed by God for exile had been fulfilled and he prayed a prayer of repentance and God brought Judah home? (Daniel 9:2-3).

Comment: https://jewsforjudaism.org/knowledge/articles/answers/jewish-polemics/texts/daniel-9-a-true-biblical-interpretation/

Comment: What Daniel was capable of is quite different from what we are capable of. While he wasn't a prophet, he had access to a divine connection that we don't have.

Comment: You don't have access to a divine connection?  Why?  What makes you say this?

Comment: "A" sure. The same as Daniel? Nope.

Comment: In reading what you said, I see how thinking that some calamity was to lie ahead for you could strike fear.  I more saw it as hopeful that it has now gone by.  I pray you all well, and am humbled by your faith and endurance.